# How do I find out the new position of actor in libgdx after using the touchDragged method?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I need your help!

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;

public class TriAngle extends Figure implements InputProcessor {

    private float w = 800;
    private float h = 600;


    public TriAngle() {

        setTextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("TriAngle.png")));
        setBounds(0, 0, w / 4, h / 4);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int i) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int i) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char c) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        if(screenX>0&&screenX<200) {
            this.setPosition(screenX, screenY, 0);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int x, int y) {
      /* if (x >= 0) {
            this.setPosition(x,y);
        }*/

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int i) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In the touchDragged method, I move the actor only if the mouse click is in the x coordinate between 0 and 200. I need to be able to move the actor by clicking on the place where its current position is.

Comment: There's a `Actor.getX()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Actor.getX()` and the `Actor.getWidth()` methods you can know its current position and if the touch happened inside its bounds:

```java
@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    if(screenX >= getX() && screenX <= getX() + getWidth() &&
        screenY >= getY() && screenY <= getY() + getHeight()) {
        this.setPosition(screenX, screenY, 0);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your advice helped me in part. I added the code like this:                     public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {

        if((screenX > getX() && screenX < getX() + getWidth())&&(screenY > getY() && screenY < getY() + getHeight())){
            this.setPosition(screenX, screenY, 0);
        }
        return true;
    }  But I ran into a problem that there are 4x4 cells on my stage. The Actor is selected only in the position 1 cell higher or 1 lower than it is.

Comment: Updated my answer with your modifications. I think your new problem would correspond to another question with its own details (Like the code of your 4x4 cells), please consider marking my answer as useful/correct since it helped you solve your first problem and don't worry about asking another question since that's what the community is here for :)